# Why is my testbench not driving any output?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, vivado, state-machines, testbench

In my testbench, I have connected the net `z` to the output of the `seq_det` module:

```
`timescale 1ps/1ps

module seq_det_tb;
    reg clk, rst_n, x;
    wire z;
    
    seq_det sd(clk, rst_n, x, z);
    
    always #2 clk = ~clk;

    initial begin
        {clk, x} = 0;
        
        $monitor("%0t: x = %0b, z = %0b", $time, x, z);
        
        // Dump waves
        $dumpfile("seq_det.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0);
        
        #1 rst_n = 0;
        #2 rst_n = 1;
        
        #3 x = 1;
        #4 x = 1;
        #4 x = 0;
        #4 x = 1;
        #4 x = 0;
        #4 x = 1;
        #4 x = 0;
        #4 x = 1;
        #4 x = 0;
        #4 x = 1;
        #4 x = 0;
        
        #10 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

This is `seq_det.v` (synthesized without any errors):

```
`timescale 1ps/1ps

module seq_det(
    input clk, rst_n, x,
    output reg out
);

    wire z;

    `ifdef MOORE_DET_NONOV
        moore_det_nonov SD1(clk, rst_n, x, z);

    `elsif MOORE_DET_OV
        moore_det_ov SD2(clk, rst_n, x, z);

    `elsif MEALY_DET_NONOV
        mealy_det_nonov SD3(clk, rst_n, x, z);

    `elsif MEALY_DET_OV
        mealy_det_ov SD4(clk, rst_n, x, z);
    `endif

    always @(*) begin
        out = z;
    end

endmodule
```

But, the net `z` in the testbench isn't driving any value as shown in the console output below:

```
0: x = 0, z = x
6: x = 1, z = x
14: x = 0, z = x
18: x = 1, z = x
22: x = 0, z = x
26: x = 1, z = x
30: x = 0, z = x
34: x = 1, z = x
38: x = 0, z = x
42: x = 1, z = x
46: x = 0, z = x
$finish called at time : 56 ps
```

Can someone point out the mistake? I am using Vivado as the tool.

This is `moore_det_nonov.v`:

```
module moore_det_nonov(
    input wire clk, rst_n, x, 
    output reg z
);

    parameter A = 3'd1;
    parameter B = 3'd2;
    parameter C = 3'd3;
    parameter D = 3'd4;
    parameter E = 3'd5;
  
    reg [3:0] curr_state, next_state;

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if(!rst_n) begin
            curr_state <= A;
        end 

        else begin
            curr_state <= next_state;
        end 
    end
    
    always @(curr_state or x) begin
        case(curr_state)
            A: next_state = x ? B : A;  
            B: next_state = x ? B : C;
            C: next_state = x ? D : A;
            D: next_state = x ? B : E;
            E: next_state = x ? B : A;
            default: next_state = A;
        endcase
    end

    always @(curr_state) begin
        z = (curr_state == D) ? 1:0;
    end

endmodule
```

This the header file that I am using which I have set as global include in my Vivado project:

```
`include "defines.v"

`ifdef MOORE_DET_NONOV
`include "moore_det_nonov.v"

`elsif MOORE_DET_OV
`include "moore_det_ov.v"

`elsif MEALY_DET_NONOV
`include "mealy_det_nonov.v"

`elsif MEALY_DET_OV
`include "mealy_det_ov.v"
`endif
```

And finally, this is `defines.v` where the macros have been defined:

```
`define MOORE_DET_NONOV
// `define MOORE_DET_OV
// `define MEALY_DET_NONOV
// `define MEALY_DET_OV
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/M_Gc) to demonstrate that your Verilog code can produce 0 and 1 outputs for `z`:

```
0: x = 0, z = x
1: x = 0, z = 0
6: x = 1, z = 0
14: x = 0, z = 0
18: x = 1, z = 0
22: x = 0, z = 1
26: x = 1, z = 0
30: x = 0, z = 0
34: x = 1, z = 0
38: x = 0, z = 1
42: x = 1, z = 0
46: x = 0, z = 0
```

The problem must be with your Vivado setup.  If you are using the Vivado GUI, perhaps you can consider [using the command line instead](https://itsembedded.com/dhd/vivado_sim_1/).  I haven't tried it, but it might make problems easier to reproduce.  It is very difficult for you to share multiple screenshots and your directory structure.